# How to make visible an invisible snackbar in an if condition in Android?

Tags: java, android, android-snackbar

I have a question about Snackbar visibility. I set invisible the Snackbar on xml and I want to make it visible in an if condition but i don't know how to do it because I'm new at coding. If you can help me with this I'd be very happy.

Answer (score -1):

Try It,

```
snackbar.addCallback(new Snackbar.Callback() {

    @Override
    public void onDismissed(Snackbar snackbar, int event) {
      //see Snackbar.Callback docs for event details

    }

    @Override
    public void onShown(Snackbar snackbar) {

    }
  });
```

Answer (score -1):

Please try this code.

```
snackbar.addCallback(new Snackbar.Callback() {

    @Override
    public void onDismissed(Snackbar snackbar, int event) {
      //see Snackbar.Callback docs for event details
      ...  
    }

    @Override
    public void onShown(Snackbar snackbar) {
       ...
    }
  });
```